# Are pomegranate seeds edible?

Tags: nutrition, biology, chemistry

My dad usually eats cherry seeds, which seemed dangerous to me, so I searched it online and indeed it can be dangerous. Today, I was about to eat a pomegranate but I wasn't sure if the seeds are edible. My parents said it's okay. But that's what they said for the cherry seeds as well. So I searched it online but haven't found anything against it. Do you know of any scientific papers where pomegranate seeds are tested for any kind of dangerous substances? (P.S. I did not eat the seeds)

[image: text]
[image: chart]

Comment: I might be missing something here. Apparently, your parents say that it's safe to eat pomegranate seeds. But you don't trust them because they also say that it's safe to eat cherry seeds, and you believe that this may not be true. The article that you copied from (without linking the source, which isn't great) does not confirm your believe that cherry seeds may be dangerous, and nothing that you've found seems to suggest that pomegranate seeds are dangerous either. What's there to investigate, then? This doesn't seem to be a question that is within the scope of skeptics.SE.

Comment: @Schmuddi That's not where I got the confirmation that cherry seeds are dangerous. That's just a related article.

Comment: You can't eat any cherry pip, plum stone or peach stone that I have seen anyway (without breaking teeth), but you can eat pomegranate seeds, they are rather tasty.

Comment: @WeatherVane You break the cherry seeds open and eat the inside.

Comment: The dose makes the poison.

Comment: I had a similar question years ago, closed though :( [Has anyone died from eating amygdalin containing fruit pits?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/28444/11643)

Answer (score 9):

I've been *served* pomegranate seeds by our canteen contractor on a regular basis, as a "special extra" on burgers...

They are definitely [edible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pomegranate#Nutrition) (*and* high in fiber!). They contain [anthocyanins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthocyanin), which contribute to their color (also contained in black currant, raspberries, cherries etc.), but are — despite the "cyan" in there — harmless.