# Can eating a few cherry pits lead to cyanide poisoning?

Tags: nutrition, safety

In 2017, a [Serbian news station reported](https://www.b92.net/zdravlje/vesti.php?yyyy=2017&mm=07&dd=28&nav_id=1287529) a UK man was hospitalized after eating cherry pits.

[Google translated]

> Matthew Krim (28) was eating cherries and out of pure curiosity swallowed three along with the pits. [...] Ten minutes later he got sick and his temperature jumped. His partner Georgina Mason, 23, called an ambulance and after telling them what he had done, Krim was rushed to hospital.

The internet disagrees on the dangers.

Is there reliable research that shows adverse effects from swallowing only a few pits?

Comment: Probably a better fit for [Medical Sciences SE](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/), if for nothing else than the big whooping big disclaimer about requesting or giving health advice online they have over there...

Comment: I’ve swallowed them my whole life and never had a problem but I’ve always been curious.

Comment: @ConorHenry And you find no complaint from your other end? Lol. Naturally, anecdote won't suffice for an answer, hence the comment I suppose.

Comment: I asked a similar question, but it was closed as a duplicate (wrongly, I think).  [Has anyone died from eating fruit pits that contain amygdalin (cyanide)?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/28444/has-anyone-died-from-eating-fruit-pits-that-contain-amygdalin-cyanide)

Comment: I think this should be split up into three questions. Does swallowing a cherry pit cause cyanide poisoning? \[You need a better reference than the one provided that says "Rest assured that a small unintentional ingestion of cherry pits will not cause harm." The radio-station forum links to [a much better example](https://www.b92.net/zdravlje/vesti.php?yyyy=2017&mm=07&dd=28&nav_id=1287529)\] Does a cherry pit cause appendicitis? [None of the references make this claim] Does a cherry pit cause constipation [None of the references make this claim].

Comment: Given only one of the claims has a notability reference, I will edit to focus on that.

Comment: @OddThinking: my question was about swallowing cherry stones whole. The guy in the story cracked one open, ate the inside, than ate two more: https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-4735234/Father-three-nearly-dies-eating-cherry-stones.html

Comment: @Oddthinking, the claims about appendicitis and constipation are mention on the fora, but also I hear them randomly from people. I'm not sure it is something like an urban legend or not. Bits of plant material including has been found in inflamed appendices but rarely (I don't have the reference now), so the relationship to me is unclear.

Comment: @Ivana: We look for notability sources, so we are tackling claims that are widely believed. None of your sources were about swallowing pits whole, so I edited it to match the claim. (At least partly because *I* thought the article's claims to be a stretch - if true, I would have expected more public warnings - so it seemed like a good question.) If you can show it is widely believed, we can open a question on it.

Comment: realted: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/109132/poisonous-escoffier-recipe/109168#109168

Comment: @Ivana I would like to encourage you to pick an answer if you believe this question has been answered to your satisfaction :)

Comment: @MarkBiernacki I'm sorry, this became a real mess. I originally wanted to know if swallowing cherry pits *whole* is harmful as the old-wives tales go. Then someone changed it to be just about eating cherry pits, actually a duplicate question. To make it worse there is no definitive answer. Excellent answers here are based on theory, and state that there is not enough poison in cherry pits to make them dangerous. But the linked article describes a case of a man who had to be hospitalized after eating cherry pits. But the source, Daily Mail, is less then reputable.

Comment: @Ivana Actually, as far as I can tell, both articles are the same person/people, so while he did end up in the hospital, my guess is that it was a specific allergy or psychosomatic symptom, probably caused by being told the old wive's tale. I do avoid drawing solid conclusions, since I'm not qualified to give medical advice.

Comment: Weird. As someone who has changed a few nappies, I can assure you that cherry stones pass through the body unchanged.

Comment: @RedSonja yup that's true. In this example though, the person crushed them up pretty good. It's still very unlikely that the cherry puts were the sole cause of his visit.

Answer (score 18):

Cherries are known to contain compounds which are toxic in high enough dosages. But that ingredient is unlikely to be what caused this man's hospitalization.

**Who is the source?**

B92.org is the website of a Serbian media outlet, that has been around since 1989. They are the largest media outlet in Serbia. I couldn't find any reports of motivation/bias, systemic or otherwise. I see no reason to discredit them outright, especially in regards to this article.

**Other reportings of Cherry Pit Poisoning**

[In July 2017, the Daily Mail reported on a similar (or possibly the same) case.](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-4735234/Father-three-nearly-dies-eating-cherry-stones.html) However, in this case the man crushed them up before eating them. Given that there is a first hand telling of the events, this makes for a more reliable reporting. However, the Daily Mail has a certain reputation, which they live up to by getting something wrong.

**Is the claim plausible?**

The Daily Mail claims:

> The stones of cherries contain a compound called amygdalin, which breaks down into hydrogen cyanide when ingested.
> A lethal dose of cyanide would be 0.126g - taking into account the UK average male body weight of 84kg - and a single cherry stone contains roughly 0.17g.

The first part of this claim seems to be supported by the literature, however, the claim that a single cherry pit **contains actual cyanide** is not. If you read the article, you'll see that cite no sources for this claim, and perhaps we'll see why.

It is generally accepted that the ingredient in cherry pits that is toxic, and other stone fruits, is Amygdalin. [Amygdalin is converted to Hydrogen Cyanide in the body.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/agricultural-and-biological-sciences/amygdalin) The amount of [Amygdalin in a cherry pit is as high as 3.89mg per gram of pit](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Caroline_Orfila/publication/259514245_Amygdalin_content_of_seeds_kernels_and_food_products_commercially-available_in_the_UK/links/5b33b48eaca2720785eac5a4/Amygdalin-content-of-seeds-kernels-and-food-products-commercially-available-in-the-UK.pdf?origin=publication_detail). A cherry pit weighs about 1 gram. Being generous, lets say the 3 cherry pits weighed 4 grams, giving **15.56mg of amygdalin.**

Cyanide exposures of 1.5mg/kg are known to cause acute toxicity. [1 gram of amygdalin releases 59mg of HCN.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6041356/) This means our 15.56mg of amygdalin releases **0.918mg of cyanide.**
Amygdalin content of seeds, kernels and food products commercially-available in the UK by Islamiyat Folashade Bolarinwa, Caroline Orfila, Michael R.A. Morgan, et al.
[image: Amygdalin content of seeds, kernels and food products commercially-available in the UK by Islamiyat Folashade Bolarinwa, Caroline Orfila, Michael R.A. Morgan, et al]

**So is that enough?**

Newton et al, 1981, found an LD50 of 522mg/kg body weight, which is the lowest lethal dose found in the literature, however others note it being higher at 880mg/kg BW. [The latter study](https://www.nrcresearchpress.com/doi/pdf/10.1139/y85-177) also found that amygdalin was 100% lethal to rats (as in this entire sampling of rats died) at only 600mg/kg when administered with a compound also in cherries (beta-glucosidase). The German Federal Institute for Risk Assessment gives an acute reference dose of 75 μg CN⁻/kg in food (Abraham et al) containing intact β-glucosidase, which increases the uptake of CN⁻ in the blood.

The average weight of a European is 71kg, so the required exposure to cyanide would be 5.33 mg of cyanide for the acute toxicity, or 37.1 grams of amygdalin to meet the LD50, however, our educated guesses are an order of magnitude lower. So according to this estimate, you would need to eat about 800 ground up cherry pits to have 50% chance of death. Needless to say, any scenario approaching this is absurd.

Note that all the procedures in these studies describe grinding up the pits or stones. Given that whole cherry pits are not broken down in the stomach, this is necessary to absorb any meaningful portion of the amygdalin contained. Another consideration is that some stones become fragile and fall apart as the fruit ripens and rots, and in these cases there is some significant risk, especially with children. But since the article describes him swallowing the cherries whole, it seems highly improbable that he could have metabolized any amygdalin at all.

Given all this, its fair to say that the Daily Mail completely missed the mark by a lot here, since there is *no cyanide* in cherry pits, and it's doubtful he ground them up to same standard as the studies. Furthermore, grinding them with your teeth will probably result in the shell having sharp edges, causing what's known as a "mechanical stomach ache" as it scratched his innards on the way down.
It would still not be fair to doubt the man's story, since Dr. Google has terrible beside manner and will scare the hell out of you. It's also possible that an allergy was triggered or that there were other complications.

**Conclusions**

- **The theoretical exposure to amygdalin was over 800 times lower than any known threshold for affects of acute cyanide poisoning**
- The theoretical exposure to hydrogen cyanide was also at least 30 times lower than any known threshold for acute affects of cyanide poisoning. These numbers are also obtained using **finely ground** pits, not chewed up pits.
- While there are clear cases of poisoning ingesting plum and apricot pits, the articles I saw did not mention similar incidents with cherry pits.
- In the case described in the b92.org news article, the amount described could **not** have been enough to cause the hospitalization, since it was not a large enough dose, nor was it ground up. We can't rule out an allergic reaction
- In the case that the dailymail.co.uk reported its plausible he did get sick from cyanide poisoning, however, it would have been far from life threatening. My guess is that this was either psychosomatic (the result of googling if its ok to eat cherry pits) or an allergic reaction.
- Despite all this, B92.org, as a media network, has existed since 1989 and is known for being the only major news network in Serbia. So there is no reason to assume that the reporting was biased or motivated to show harm.
- **None of this should dissuade from going to the hospital if you are feeling the effects of cyanide poisoning or an allergic reaction! Especially if you are dealing with children.**

**BONUS: The process of conversion of amygdalin to cyanide in the body. AND! The symptoms of acute cyanide poisoning**

[image: Conversion of amygdalin to cyanide in the body]

> Symptoms of cyanide poisoning include stomach cramps, headache, nausea and vomiting, and can culminate in cardiac arrest, respiratory failure, coma and death.

Comment: As a personal note, I once made myself a smoothie using frozen cherries, drank a bunch of it, then noticed a shard of cherry pit.  95% (plus) of the cherries in the bag were pitted, but not all, so I freaked and called poison control, who told me to not worry because they'd have to be finely ground up. I disregarded this, because I was still freaking out and went to the hospital. Huge waste of time.
edited for accuracy :)

Comment: The Daily Mail reports on the same case, the guy actually cracked open and ate several pits and according to the Daily mail at least, had to go to hospital. https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-4735234/Father-three-nearly-dies-eating-cherry-stones.html It is a bit of a mix up, my question was about swallowing pits whole but it was changed by others.

Comment: In addition, the human body detoxifies cyanide (CN⁻) by an enzyome (rhodanase) transforming it into thiocyanate (SCN⁻ aka rhodanide). This is apparently (literature my answer over on cooking.sx https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/109168/52931) fast, but our sulfur reserves are limited. Making sure that there is sufficient sulfur for the detoxification by giving thiosulfate (S<sub>2</sub>O<sub>3</sub>²⁻) is one of the treatment options for acute cyanide poisoning. The German Federal Institute for Risk Assessment gives an acute reference dose of 75 μg CN⁻/kg body weight, so the estimated amount

Comment: Yeah, I mentioned that there's basically no way he could have absorbed any from swallowing the pits whole, but in the article it says he crushed them up. I will do an update to my answer.

Comment: would be officially considered OK for anyone above 14 kg body weight. Of course, if for some reason his sulfur reserves were already depleted, the bets would be off again. Otherwise, the dailymail photo looks as if even about 10x as much would have been within the limits (and those limits have a safety margin for vegetables that contain enzymes leading to a fast hydrolysis of amygdalin). Almost unrelated: crushing the pits with your teeth will lead to quite sharp edges, and I wouldn't wonder if they cause "mechanical stomach ache".

Comment: @cbeleitesunhappywithSX Yup, totally agree. I imagine it would have been somewhat painful to swallow as well. Also, I think your comment got cut off while you were saying what the ARFD would be for a 71kg man (which would be 5.33mg)
Could you help me cite that source? Either a link, doi entry, or book? I couldn't find it by googling.

Comment: @MarkBiernacki: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00204-015-1479-8 it's the Abraham et al from my answer on cooking.sx (and I didn't calculate for a 71 kg man, I calculated the other way round: how small can one be to safely eat a meal with 920 mg CN⁻)

Comment: This is just a really high quality answer.  Props

Comment: "It is generally accepted that the ingredient in cherry pits that is toxic, and other stone fruits, is Amygdalin." Not just stone fruit. Apples, for instance, also have amygdalin.

Comment: This is a perfect answer *except* for the focus on LD50 rather than the LOAEL. The original claim says that the man experienced serious symptoms and was hospitalized, not that he was on death's door. As an extreme comparison, the LD50 for ipecac syrup is around 200 mg/kg, but you'd definitely end up in the hospital if you accidentally consumed a tiny fraction of that.

Comment: @Sneftel not sure why I didn't base it on that... updating rn :)

Comment: The Daily Mail is no doubt reporting on the same case; the difference in names is because B92 transliterated the names into Serbian. The answer should be edited to reflect that.

Comment: @Laurel, I'm not entirely happen with the quality of writing/clarity on the edit I made, but I probably sunk enough time into this answer. I'm somewhat of a SE noob, but I think people can edit my answer. I wouldn't mind at all if someone changed the phrasing to something more appealing.

Answer (score 3):

[Poison.org](https://www.poison.org/articles/i-swallowed-a-cherry-pit-184) says:

> The dangerous chemical found in the seeds of stone fruits is called
> amygdalin. Poisoning can occur when the pit and seed are crushed or
> chewed before swallowing, releasing the amygdalin. Amygdalin is then
> converted by the body to cyanide.
>
> [...]
>
> The amount of amygdalin in the seeds of stone fruits varies widely,
> both between different types of stone fruits (e.g., cherries vs.
> plums) and even within the same type of fruit (e.g., cherries from one
> tree vs. cherries from another tree or geographic location). This
> makes it difficult to determine the number of seeds it takes for
> poisoning to occur. In general, unintentional ingestions do not lead
> to poisoning because it is unlikely that someone would chew or crush
> the kernels/seeds prior to swallowing them, and because unintentional
> ingestions tend to be of small amounts.

So it is unlikely, but not impossible, that eating a few cherry pits lead to cyanide poisoning.

Comment: So if someone had the bright idea to crush cherry seeds and ingest the result - or lacked the foresight to not dump whole cherries into a mixer - then they _would_ be in trouble?

Comment: I'd quibble with "a few cherry pits" here. That's an assumption, as John suggests above, that crushing and intentionally eating the pit innards of "a few cherry pits" would cause poisoning. Per your source, that's virtually unknowable without a lot of details. +1 for the answer effort, however.

Comment: As with everything in nature that's "poisonous", dose makes the poison. There's no such thing as "would", just "could" in increasing amounts of likelihood...

Comment: Water can cause [water-intoxication](https://www.webmd.com/food-recipes/news/20161103/water-can-it-be-too-much-of-a-good-thing#1). There are couple of very sad cases of clear abuse where parents forced their children to drink water or soda until they died. Even [adults](http://www.nbcnews.com/id/16614865/ns/us_news-life/t/woman-dies-after-water-drinking-contest/) can kill themselves doing this if they don't know it is harmful. So basically anything can become toxic in large enough quantities, nevermind the stuff that is classified as "poisonous".

Comment: Emphasis needs to be put on the fact that swallowing a cherry pit whole will not poison you. It needs to be crushed at least, but typically it would have to be fully powdered to be taken up by the body.

Comment: @MarkBiernacki: That is a weird proviso that the OP seems to care about too, and I don't know why. Who is carefully swallowing pips like medication without chewing them?

Comment: @Oddthinking I think Ivana is talking swallowing the pits whole, not the entire cherry. But I did spot something else about these to accounts... I'm pretty they're the same person. The same name and age is given to the spouse, and I'm pretty sure Metju = Matthew and Krim = Creme if you do a "Phonetic" translation in the Bosnian alphabet.

Comment: @Mark: Your second point should be a comment on the other answer. Your first point didn't address my question. Why is emphasis required  for a situation that almost never happens?

Comment: @Oddthinking I'm not sure what your question is then? I don't think it's very common to intentionally eat a cherry pit, but if you were to ingest one, it would as an unbroken pit. I don't think Ivana is asking about the risks of swallowing cherries whole, without chewing. After reading all her comments, I don't see where you could have gotten this impression :(

Comment: "I don't see where you could have gotten this impression" I haven't got the impression anyone is talking about swallowing a cherry whole. That's not what I wrote. "if you were to ingest one, it would as an unbroken pit." That's the assumption I don't understand. If a someone asked me "Can I eat cherry pits?" the answer is "NO!" not "Yes, but only if you promise not to accidentally chew. Alternatively, it is okay if you also swallow activated charcoal, or induce vomiting afterwards." I don't understand why you think this "swallow whole" caveat deserves special emphasis.

Comment: I mean I guess I understand your point, however, cherry pits are not pleasant to chew. 
Since you can accidentally chew swallow a cherry pit whole, but you can't accidentally chew and then swallow a pit, I believe that there is a distinction worth noting. Just my opinion, and it's definitely something anyone could address (or not) in an answer.